# Dark triangle on shadow edge (cycle mode only)

Tags: shadows

I just place the Zuzanne's head on the center,  a light, and a camera.
In cycle render mode, I got some small dark triangle on the shadow edge.
In Eevee render mode, Everything is ok.

It seems not a z-fighting, face orientation is OK.
Material is not related to this. I tried to remove all material, triangle is still there.

It is a simple scene.
Did I do anything wrong?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try to increase Suzanne's Subdivision levels with Subsurface Modifier.

Try to increase Lamp Angle.

Or you can increase Shadow Terminator Offset for smoother shadow transitions.

Image below: Shadow Terminator offset 0.00 vs 0.1:

[image]

Comment: Increase subdivision doesn't work. Increase light angle may work for some area, but the problem occurs on another area. Shade offset improved, but not solve the case. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: I tried and studied for a long time, I realized this problem is about shade. It relates to modeling , shading. I have to study more.

Comment: If you made no changes to the model, the shading (geometry, normals) of the default Suzanne's head is perfectly fine.

Comment: Now I know this problem is called shadow terminator problem. It can be solved by shadow terminator setting in blender 2.9. Of course subdiv can improve the problem also, but it increases face too much. I think I have to find a balance between them,  Thanks.